# Percentage symbol with csvsimple package

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I'm using package `csvsimple` to read `.csv` files. The problem is, in some of the cells I have percentages, like:

```
a,b
1,10%
3,16%
```

If I leave the `%`s, everything after the first `%` is omitted, that is, it's behaving like a comment. If I escape `%` with `\%` I get compilation errors.

Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{tab.csv}
\end{document}
```

where `tab.csv`:

```
a,b
1,2%
2,5%
```

The same problem happens with `datatool` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a small example?

Comment: Without an example it is untested but probably {\catcode`\%=12 \csvreader{...}}

Answer (score 4):

You can add the possibility to evaluate some keys, which is not allowed with the default `\csvautotabular` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\csvloopx}[2][]{\csvloop{#1,#2}}
\newcommand{\csvautotabularx}[2][]{\csvloopx[#1]{autotabular={#2}}}
\newcommand{\respectpercent}{\catcode`\%=12\relax}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabularx[before table=\respectpercent]{tab.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You get a similar effect with `datatool` by using the `\DTLloadrawdb` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\DTLloadrawdb{tab}{tab.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{tab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: isnt there a simpler way with either datatool or csvsimple?

Comment: @FernandoAntonioNogueira I think that this *is* the simplest way for `csvsimple`. Not sure about `datatool`, but `\DTLloadrawdb` seems the way to go. May you add also an example of what you're trying with `datatool`?

Comment: \documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
  \DTLloaddb{ash}{ash.csv}
  \DTLdisplaydb{ash}
\end{document}

Comment: @Fernando: IMHO the simplest and easiest way is to process the `.csv` beforehand and escape all occurrences of `%` to `\%`. Another approach is to remove the percent sign from the `.csv` and add it later while in the `.tex` document.

Comment: if you mean putting a \ in every occurrence of the % in the csv file, I have done it and it wont work.